# copy & copy_if vs remove_copy & remove_copy_if

Tags: c++, algorithm

I try to find any difference between copy(copy_if) and  remove_copy(remove_copy_if) stl algorithms but it seems that there are no any practical differences instead of that:

> [Source and destination ranges cannot overlap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy)
>   in remove_copy algorithm

**Is there really any significant and practical difference in these algorithms?**

Comment: Don't they do the opposite? That seems like a practical difference.

Comment: Prior to C++11 it was more work to negate a predicate :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) only copies elements satisfying a given predicate, [remove_copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) on the other hand copies only elements that **do not** satisfy a specified predicate. Thus the two functions complement each other, they do not do the same.

By the way for copy_if there is also similar statement `The behavior is undefined if the source and the destination ranges overlap.` Thus it may not be checked but it is very bad idea to have the source and destination overlapping.

Comment: Assuming the predicate can logically be inverted, the result is the same for both functions, aren't they?

Comment: Yes the result is the same. And each predicate can be logically inverted by adding a `!` to its return value. Still, what are you saying?

Comment: Its little bit clear now, but I think the main problem for me to understand it is in the name of algorithm remove_copy which as though promises to us something to remove from an initial sequence and then to copy. Thanx for explanation!

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Well, as each function call can easily be transferred to the a call of the other function, there seems not to be a difference, apart from readability and the undefined behaviour in some cases.

Comment: @Anton -- concerning the names, the basic form of the algorithm is `remove`, which removes the values that satisfy the predicate. When you go to `remove_copy` the change is that the **result** is a copy of what the result of plain `remove` would have been. In general, that's the difference between non-`copy` and `copy` versions of an algorithm: it's about where the result goes. The non-`copy` version applies the algorithm in place; the copy version puts results in a separate output range, leaving the input range untouched.

Comment: For me 'copy_remove' sounds more logically/sequently))

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev where is the statement that `copy_if` is undefined for overlapping ranges? I understand a trivial `copy` may be inlined to `memcpy` which requires that the source and destination ranges do not overlap, but that is not possible with `copy_if`. The only other issue would be `restrict` semantics which is C99 only.

Comment: The quote is from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) point 1).

Comment: `copy_not` and `copy_if_not` would have been better names? Consistent with `find_if_not`, for example